# How to decrease the size of an entry in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, size

I want to decrease the size of an entry in tkinter python. ive already asked about label but i havent used fyi

the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

top = Tk()
top.title("Hello wold")
top.geometry("300x300")

ei = StringVar()
ei1 = StringVar()

def karma():
    try:
        ee = ei.get()
        ee1 = ei1.get()
        ez = int(ee) + int(ee1)
        return messagebox.showinfo('message', f'{ee} + {ee1} = {ez}')
    except ValueError:
        return messagebox.showinfo('message', f'ERROR')

name = Label(top,text="1st no. : ").place(x = 20,y = 50)
e = Entry(top,textvariable=ei).place(x = 100, y = 50)
name1 = Label(top,text="2nd no. : ").place(x = 20,y = 100)
e1 = Entry(top,textvariable=ei1).place(x = 100, y = 100)
b = Button(top, text="Click here", command=karma).place(x = 20,y = 150)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"ive already asked about label but i havent used fyi:"_ There are two answers below your question and you have not provided feedback to either one on why you haven't used it or why it wasn't what you are expecting.

Comment: "decrease the size" can mean many things. Do you want a smaller font? Do you want the widget to be longer or shorter? Do you want it to be taller? Do you want larger borders? Smaller?

Answer (score 0):

you may use the `font` option in `Entry` to adjust the size.

Here is an example (to change it to 8pts)

```
import tkFont

helv8 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=8)

e = Entry(top, font = helv8, textvariable=ei).place(x = 100, y = 50)
```